How to disable Ubuntu 24.04's toggle maximize on titlebar single click?
I'm used to having to double click to toggle a window's maximization state. Right now, if I single-click on a window, it toggles its maximization state (although only when the window is already maximized).
For example,  I'll have an app open and it's maximized, then I click once on the titlebar and it becomes smaller. I don't want that, I only want that when I double-click, and I can't find the corresponding dconf setting.
I've noticed that this only happens in crome, so it's probably an issue with the non-GNOME titlebar.
Is there a way to fix this for Chrome? It's very annoying. Thanks!

Oh lord I thought I was the only one dealing with this. It's too annoying, especially when I keep accidentally tapping the panel bar. Disabling the "Ubuntu Tiling Assistant" extension did it for me

I had the same problem and disabling "Ubuntu Tiling Assistant" extension solved that for me.
You can disable it using the Extensions app or by running this command:
gnome-extensions disable tiling-assistant@ubuntu.com

or by going to Settings → Ubuntu Desktop and toggle Enhanced Tiling off.

Oh thanks bro :)))

Thank you thank you thank you! Most annoying feature EVER! I think I've unexpectedly clicked the title bar a billion times.

Starting with Ubuntu 23.10, the Tiling Assistant extension has been incorporated in the default Ubuntu installation, in order to allow for some more advanced tiling options, such as quarter tiling. So this is an issue of this extension, that has been reported on the extension's GitHub at least two times:

Clicking the top bar un-maximizes window in Gnome 46

Create a settings toggle to disable the Single click on titlebar toggles maximization behavior


As the developer (Leleat) informs in a comment:

"Single click to maximize" isn't a feature, it's a bug. It's already fixed in the latest version of Tiling Assistant but it didn't make it into Ubuntu yet. I don't know how Ubuntu's extension update process works. I guess you'll get the fix with the next point release... but this is just a guess, I don't know.

So you can either wait until Ubuntu updates the extension at some point (in the meantime you can disable it as suggested in Sadra Saderi's answer to workaround the issue), or install the latest version of the extension separately from GNOME Extensions.
If you have disabled Tiling Assistant and you still experience the issue, make sure to check if it is caused by some other extension and report it at the relevant place, or if you find that it is not caused by an extension, report it against the mutter package in Launchpad.
